# Spring - how to make global URL controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a lot of controllers in my Spring web app and I want to know, how to build something like controller or filter, for execution his code, when in URL has comething ..... ?clearCache=Y ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend [HandlerInterceptorAdapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/HandlerInterceptorAdapter.html) and configure it:

```
public class CacheClearingHandlerInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

  @Override
  public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

    if("Y".equals(request.getParameter("clearCache"))) {
      doCoolStuff();
    }

    return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
  }

}
```

In your Web Application Context Configuration (`mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml`):

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**"/>
        <bean class="com.example.project.CacheClearingHandlerInterceptor"/>
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this on Controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/urlpPath", params="clearCache=Y", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Params is what used to restrict url with that value of a parameter.

Comment: Not exactly "global" ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want this feature for any request you can achieve this by either implementing a request filter or an interceptor.

One example of this kind of behavior you can find in Spring itself. The `LocaleChangeInterceptor` which checks for a parameter `lang` and modifies the current request locale.